# Benefits of integration platform

Tags: architecture, enterprise-architecture

We are looking at introducing an integration platform.

In the begining it is an extra layer and an extra cost. But after a while the service that a new system needs will be available on the integration platform, therefore saving development effort.

Question is does anyone know of any studies that look at how long the above "a while" is?

Or are there any ROI studies on the use of integration platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply google "ESB case study", you should be able to find a vast array of information to help your cause.